# python value becomes zero, how to prevent

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, statistics, rounding

I have a numerical problem while doing likelihood ratio tests in python. I'll not go into too much detail about what the statistics mean, my problems comes down to calculating this:

```
LR = LR_H0 / LR_h1
```

where `LR` is the number of interest and `LR_H0` and `LR_H1` are numbers that can be *VERY* close to zero. This leads to a few numerical issues; if `LR_H1` is too small then python will recognise this as a division by zero.

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Also, although this is not the main issue, if `LR_H1` is small enough to allow the division then the fraction `LR_H0 / LR_h1` might become too big (I'm assuming that python also has an upper limit value of what a float can be).

Any tips on what the best way is to circumvent this problem? I'm considering doing something like:

```
def small_enough( num ): 
    if num == 0.0: 
        return *other small number* 
    else: 
    return num
```

But this is not ideal because it would approximate the `LR` value and I would like to guarantee some precision.

Comment: I believe you can find your answers here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: No need to assume any limits. Just check with [sys.float_info](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Work with logarithms. Take the log of all your likelihoods, and add or subtract logarithms instead of multiplying and dividing. You'll be able to work with much greater ranges of values without losing precision.

Comment: To complement this, you can also use floats with a greater range, such as float128 instead of the default float64.

Comment: @J.Martinot-Lagarde: finding an efficient float128 implementation for Python would be a bit tricky, though.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I was thinking about numpy, which has float128.

Comment: @J.Martinot-Lagarde: Well, sort of.  NumPy's float128 is almost always just the usual x87 80-bit extended precision type, padded with zero bytes.  There's no support for true IEEE 754 float128 on any common OS.  But it's true that the 80-bit type could be used to provide some extra range for the exponent, since it's got a 15-bit exponent instead of an 11-bit one.